# How do I selectively create symbolic links to specific files in another directory in LINUX?

Tags: linux, bash, symlink

I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing this, but I need to create symbolic links for certain files in one directory and place the symbolic links in another directory.

For instance, I want to link all files with the word "foo" in its name in the current directory bar1 that does not have the extension ".cc" and place the symbolic links in a directory bar2.

I was wondering if there was single line command that could accomplish this in LINUX bash.

Comment: You should probably just write a simple shell script to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are in a directory that contains directories `bar1` and `bar2`:

```
find bar1 -name '*foo*' -not -type d -not -name '*.cc' -exec ln -s $PWD/'{}' bar2/ \;
```

Comment: I believe the requirement is to find files whose names contain `foo` and do not end in `.cc` (not files in a directory named foo).

Comment: You are right, I misread the question.  I corrected my answer.

Comment: It shouldn't, but try the advice in the answer by @HaiWu (which is pretty much the same answer as this) and change add `echo` before `ln` so you can see exactly what command would run.

Comment: I think I'm going to combine the first part of this one with a forloop instead.  Seem to be having a lot of difficulty with the -exec ln -s $PWD/'{}' bar2/ \; portion of the code.

Comment: For some reason, the -exec ln -s $PWD/'{}' portion of the command is concatenating the full filesystem filename to itself again, resulting in broken links.

Comment: Ahh figured out the problem...the first part of the command: find bar1 -name '*foo*' -not -type d -not -name '*.cc' returns a list of the full filesystem filenames of the files to be symlinked...so in the second part where it says -exec ln -s $PWD/'{}' bar2/ \; it should really just be -exec ln -s '{}' bar2/ \;...but thanks a bunch for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: I just looked this up: apparently when you give `find` an absolute path to search, it will return absolute paths.  When given a relative path, it returns relative paths.  So this is why my example worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
cd bar1
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*foo*' -not -name '*.cc'  -exec echo ln -s $PWD/{} ../bar2 \;
```

Once you are satisfied with the dry run, remove `echo` from the command and run it for real.

Answer (score 2):

This is easily handled with extended globbing:

```
shopt -s extglob
cd bar2
ln -s ../bar1/foo!(*.cc) .
```

If you really want it all on one line, just use the command separator:

```
shopt -s extglob; cd bar2; ln -s ../bar1/foo!(*.cc) .
```

The two examples are identical, but the first is much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

This technically doesn't count as a one line answer...but it can be pasted in a single instance and should do what you are looking for.

```
list=`ls | grep foo | grep -v .cc`;for file in $list;do ln $file /bar2/;done
```

Comment: looks like the back ticks were left out around the variable "list", be sure to include them.

Comment: Don't forget `ln -s` to create symbolic link as opposed to hard links

Comment: This is made of winning