# Create symbolic link from find

Tags: sed, find

I'm trying to create a symbolic link (soft link) from the results of a find command. I'm using sed to remove the ./ that precedes the file name. I'm doing this so I can paste the file name to the end of the path where the link will be saved. I'm working on this with Ubuntu Server 8.04.

I learned from this post, which is kind of the solution to my problem but not quite-

[How do I selectively create symbolic links to specific files in another directory in LINUX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888105/how-do-i-selectively-create-symbolic-links-to-specific-files-in-another-director)

The resulting file name didn't work, though, so I started trying to learn awk and then decided on sed.

I'm using a one-line loop to accomplish this. The problem is that the structure of the loop is separating the filename, creating a link for each word in the filename. There are quite a few files and I would like to automate the process with each link taking the filename of the file it's linked to.

I'm comfortable with basic bash commands but I'm far from being a command line expert. I started this with ls and awk and moved to find and sed. My sed syntax could probably be better but I've learned this in two days and I'm kind of stuck now.

for t in `find -type f -name "*txt*" | sed -e 's/.//' -e 's$/$$'; do echo ln -s $t ../folder2/$t;` done

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can avoid the `./` in the output from `find` by passing a list of paths. `find */ -options ...` I guess there may be an option for it, too.

Comment: The problem with the non-working links is that relative path names need to be relative to the link destination. Rewrite to start the loop one directory up (`find source -options ... -exec ln -s  '{}' target \;`), use absolute paths, or extend your `sed` script to resolve the link target relative to the destination (trivially add `../source/` in front). The first argument to `ln -s` does not get rewritten in any way, it is used verbatim as the contents of the symbolic link, there is no requirement or check that it resolves to an existing file at the time of link creation.

Comment: I think you mean `sed 's%^\./%%'`. In order to allow a slash in the regex, `sed` allows you to use any punctuation character after the `s` command, although a slash is the traditional default delimiter, mimicking the search character in `vi`, and `ed` before it. Alternatively, you can backslash-escape the delimiter to quote it as a literal character in the expression.

Answer (score 15):

Easier:

Go to the folder where you want to have the files in and do:

```
find /path/with/files -type f -name "*txt*" -exec ln -s {} . ';'
```

Answer (score 2):

Execute your for loop like this:

```
(IFS=$'\n'; for t in `find -type f -name "*txt*" | sed 's|.*/||'`; do ln -s $t ../folder2/$t; done)
```

By setting the IFS to only a newline, you should be able to read the entire filename without getting splitted at space.

The brackets are to make sure the loop is executed in a sub-shell and the IFS of the current shell does not get changed.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. I wasn't sure if I was using the find and sed commands properly and you helped me see where I need to make the necessary changes. In my reading, I saw that I could use other characters (i.e., %) in sed. The example I saw used $ so I tried it and it worked. I'll try to modify my sed syntax using your tips and hopefully get this working. Thanks again.