# Why isn't my command to create symlinks to one type of file within every directory in my current directory working?

Tags: linux, bash, bioinformatics

I have a directory containing about 500 directories in it. In each one of these 500 directories, there are two files I want, one ending in .bam and one ending in .bai. I'm trying to create symlinks to all files ending in .bam or .bai to a new location.

My directories are structured as:

```
/Parent_Directory/[500_Subdirectories]/file.bam
```

and my destination directory being:

```
/New_Directory/bam_folder/
```

Now, I'm running into issues with my current code:

```
for d in Parent_Directory; do  
    ( cd "$d" && ln -s *.ba* New_Directory/Bam_Folder ); 
done
```

What seems to keep happening is that I create a symlink in my Bam_Folder directory to a nonexistent file file called *.ba*

What exactly am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Symlinks can't be relative. It should be the complete filepath.

Comment: Thanks for the help! How would I be able to do that for every file in each of the directories if the directory and file names are variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`find`](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html);

---

Improved answer based on [@oguz ismail's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65360143/why-isnt-my-command-to-create-symlinks-to-one-type-of-file-within-every-directo/65360400?noredirect=1#comment115552332_65360400) wich prevents the program to run for each file, instead it's only executed once for all the files;

```
find /Parent_Directory/ -iname '*.bam' -exec ln -s -t /New_Directory/bam_folder {} +
```

---

Original answer:

```
find /Parent_Directory/ -iname '*.bam' -exec ln -s {} /New_Directory/bam_folder/ ';'
```

- `-iname '*.bam'`

  - Files ending in `.bam`
- `-exec ln -s {} /New_Directory/bam_folder/`

  - `{}` is the path of the found item (full)
  - Second argument is the path the symlink will go to

---

[Create symbolic link from find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577769/create-symbolic-link-from-find)

---

Note; I've not tested the command since we're not sure how the file structure looks like